# How can I convert a Digital Image into a "Pointilism" Template for use in a real life minimal design?

Tags: cmyk, minimalistic

I recently saw this article about a man using pointillism with "push pins" to make the face of the CEO of Pinterest. https://www.fastcompany.com/1670620/watch-this-guy-draw-pinterests-ceo-using-22765-pushpins

I wanted to achieve something like this automatically. Rather, using pixels.

I want to be able to specify (Or just using cmyk/rgb would work) a few specific colors. And be able to "Automatically" generate this style of image by placing those colors together in different arrangements to achieve different colors.

*This is how pointillism works in real life. In art class years ago, I was given 4 colors (cymk) and was supposed to place them so small next to each other in different arrangements to achieve different brightness levels.*

I want to create this effect so I can print out "templates" and make pointillism-esque pictures.  Its part of a minimal design effort in one of our rooms.

Comment: if there isnt an automatic way, atleast if there is a tool that can generate mutliple  "colors" to make up one color of a single pixel, or even a guide.

Either method works fine.

Comment: The pins in the reference are placed in a hexagon pattern. If you change this to square pixels it's kind of what digital images do already. They use a limited set of colors which creates the illusion of the colors of reality due to their placement. But you might not think it's so noticeable because there are so many different colors. *Indexed color mode* which can be set to a small fixed palette might be what you are looking for. Which image editor do you have access to? Photoshop?

Comment: @Wolff Alright, I get it, but I still kindof want to see if I can create the ffect even with pixels. Also I have Paint.NET, Gimp, and can "possibly" get photoshop if needed.

Edit: someone answered what you just mentioned for gimp

Answer (score 1):

This is for Photoshop. You could reduce the image size, so it's around 150px wide or thereabouts.

Then do *Image > Mode > Indexed*, and apply the following settings shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou. Im assuming this is for Gimp?

Comment: @MisterSirCode Sorry, no it was for Photoshop, but it should be possible in GIMP too.

Comment: @MisterSirCode In GIMP you could make a limited custom colour palette, and apply it using Image > Mode > Indexed. [See example](https://imgur.com/ht82BUu)

Comment: Well, I just assumed it was gimp due to your profile picture (I assumed you used it) but I actually use Paint.NET but cant find a plugin for it. If needed, I can download gimp or photoshop

Comment: @MisterSirCode  Paint.NET has G'mic filter collection plugin. It has artistic filter "Shapism" which makes numerous different pointillizations. Unfortunately it's so complex to set up that I haven't still got with it expected results. Obviously someone with bigger brain is needed. But you can try. Good luck!

Comment: @user287001 Thanks for the info, Ill check it out